# How do I pass a JSON response from VB to JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, webforms

How do I pass a JSON response from VB to JS?

I'm in the middle of updating a company website that accepts payments via JSON request/response. It's written in VB and so far I've been able to successfully send the JSON request and receive the response, but my issue is passing the response from VB to JS to allow the bank's external JS file inject their payment page into my page's DIV tag.

I'm very new at this and have tried many things with no luck. The closest I get is by passing the JSON response to a hidden input field and have a JS script pick up the value via document.getElementById, but the hidden input field only gets the opening {.

The JSON response is structured as follows:

```
{"response" : {"success":"true","ticket":"random ticket number from bank"}}
```

Here's the code snippet so far. I apologize, it's messy.

```
Dim webClient As New WebClient()
Dim resByte As Byte()
Dim resString As String
Dim reqString() As Byte

Try
    webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
    reqString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented))
    resByte = webClient.UploadData(Me.urlToPost, "post", reqString)
    resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append(resString)
    Dim JSONData As String = sb.ToString()
    Dim p As Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
    p.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "alert", JSONData)

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(String.Format("<input id=""jsonResponse"" value=""{0}"">", resString))

    Dim jScript As String = "<script>var myCheckout = new bankCheckout();myCheckout.setMode('qa');myCheckout.setCheckoutDiv('bankCheckout');var form1Display = document.getElementById('form1');function showCheckout(){form1Display.style.visibility = 'hidden';bankCheckoutDisplay.style.visibility = 'visible';}var bankCheckoutDisplay = document.getElementById('bankCheckout');let result = document.querySelector('.result');var json = document.getElementById('jsonResponse');var obj = JSON.parse(json);alert(obj.response.ticket);myCheckout.startCheckout(obj.response.ticket);showCheckout();</script>"


    p.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Script", jScript, False)

    webClient.Dispose()
    Return True            
            
End Try
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to pass it back to Javascript? It sounds like it could be a security issue, especially with payment stuff. If so, then you can adapt your `RegisterStartupScript` to send an additional message, with the JSON text as an argument, to a Javascript function.

Comment: I actually already had this working in concept in Javascript with Node.js, but abandoned it due to security concerns. If I can avoid sending it back to JS that would be awesome.

Comment: Then this sounds like you just want to send the JSON somewhere else from the back end. How you do that depends, of course, on how it should be received. Should it be a REST call, a database call, what?

Comment: The initial JSON request to the bank, when approved, sends back the response from the bank I noted with a ticket number. I then execute the "myCheckout.startCheckout(Ticket Number from Response)", which is declared in the externally referenced JS file on the bank's server. This will then populate my DIV tag with the bank's payment page. Unfortunately since I'm learning as I go here, I couldn't confidently say if it's a REST or Database call. How could I find out?

Comment: If you just want to put some of the data from the JSON on the web page, then you should just be able to construct the elements you need in the code behind, and put it where you need it. I was unclear on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you just want to display the information you received. Maybe this isn't a VB thing at all, but you just want to take a web page from the bank and display it inset in your page?

Comment: The bank's payment page hinges on me passing the ticket number to the noted function. The DIV tag on my Master page will be the holder of this once the function runs successfully. What do you think would be the most secure way to pass this to the JS function? Could you provide a sample code?

Comment: You must have some control on which you will display the ticket number. I would think, for example if it is an asp:textbox with `runat='server"`, you would simply use something like `TicketNumber.Text = ticket`, where `ticket` is the deserialized JSON ticket number, and `TicketNumber` is the ID of the textbox. This would be within your DIV tag, but you shouldn't need to reference the DIV tag at all, AFAIK.

Comment: I did try sending it to an input field, but only the first { went inside. The rest was truncated for some reason even though I know the response JSON does not have any line feeds or carriage returns.

Comment: I don't mean send the whole JSON string, but just the deserialized part you want to display. A deserializing example is too long for a comment; you may need to create custom objects and things, to be able to isolate your data. Unless someone else knows of some special control or technique for displaying JSON data in a web page...

Comment: That is another point I'm stuck at. It's so much easier with Javascript, ha ha. The only examples I keep seeing to deserialize it are what you refer to, but if anyone else on here can find an easier way I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference:
https://github.com/beatum/demo-Json-manipulation-vbs

```
    'convert to JSON object
    Set JsonObject = ConvertToJSONObject(JsonData)
    'Members
    Set Members = JsonObject.Members
    'get length of array
    lenOfArray = GetByProperty(Members, "length")
    'loop
    For i = 0 To CInt(lenOfArray) - 1
       Set mem = GetByIndex(Members, i)
       Debug.Print "Name:" & mem.Name
       Debug.Print "Age:" & mem.Age
       Debug.Print "SecretIdentity:" & mem.SecretIdentity
       Set Powers = mem.Powers
       lenOfPowers = GetByProperty(Powers, "length")
       Debug.Print "################Powers#################"
       For j = 0 To CInt(lenOfPowers) - 1
          Power = GetByProperty(Powers, j)
          Debug.Print Power
       Next
    Next
   Debug.Print "......Done......"
```